# How do I make GRUB2 appear, after installing ubuntu on a drive with windows 7 (no wubi)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, grub

On a fresh Windows 7 install I installed Ubuntu 9.10, booting from the CD and chosing the first option where it installs ubuntu on another partition in the same drive as Win7 and allowing me to chose the OS at startup.

After installing Ubuntu, it asks to remove the disc and restart the computer. I did that.
**On the next boots, it logs right into windows7, without asking which OS.**

I read a bunch of stuff searching from google to reinstall grub2 with no succesa, and I formatted the drive again to reinstall windows7 and then ubuntu again to see the same thing happening again.

I'm new to linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) should do the trick, I'm not totally proficient with the new version so you should consult a guide instead. Although I did the opposite of yours where I switched to the Vista Bootloader (you should use the beta version of EasyBCD however, because that one is compatible with Windows 7, some tools will be switched though.

Comment: Guide @ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50wds2xrld4

[sorry i can't post more than one hyperlink at once yet]

Comment: It worked. Now I just need to configure GRUB2 so it doesn't appear, as I'm chosing the os with the windows EasyBCD.